Repeating SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError on Node JS API
I'm constantly receiving this error in my Node JS API:
Redis Client Error:
SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:194:118)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at node:net:337:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:657:7)

After which reconnection is taking place successfully. It does happen a few times every hour though so it can interrupt the app if an endpoint is hit at the same time.
The Redis server is hosted on Azure. The behavior is the same when running the API locally and when running on Azure App Service in production environment.
Below I have the code I'm using to set up Redis in my app.
const redis = require('redis');

const dbIndex = process.env.REDIS_DB_INDEX || 0; // Default to 0 if no index is set
const DEFAULT_TTL = parseInt(process.env.FACETS_CACHE_TTL, 10) || 1800

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: `rediss://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:6380`,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    socket_keepalive: true,
    socket: {
      tls: {
        servername: process.env.REDIS_HOST
      },
      reconnectStrategy: (retries) => {
        // This is a simple example; you can implement more complex logic.
        // For example, you can increase the delay with each retry or set a max number of retries.
        if (retries < 10) {
          // Wait 2 seconds before reconnecting, with 10 total retries
          return 2000;
        } else {
          // Stop trying after 10 attempts
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
redisClient.on('reconnecting', () => console.log('Reconnecting to Redis...'));
let isFirstConnection = true;

redisClient.on('ready', () => {
  if (isFirstConnection) {
    console.log('\nSuccessfully connected to Redis');
    isFirstConnection = false;
  } else {
    console.log('\nSuccessfully reconnected to Redis');
  }
});
  
(async () => {
try {
    await redisClient.connect();
    // select the appropriate database index
    await redisClient.sendCommand(['SELECT', dbIndex]);
    console.log(`database index: ${dbIndex}`);
    console.log(`DEFAULT_TTL = ${DEFAULT_TTL} seconds\n`);
    // Once connected, you can subscribe to events or start issuing commands as needed.
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to Redis:', err);
}
})();


I have tried
socket_keepalive: true
in the client initialization but it didn't seem to do anything. I'm not even sure if it's a valid parameter for JS environments as I've seen it being suggested for similar issues in Python.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Does your application Redis client is selecting correct database index at the initial successful connection?


I have tried socket_keepalive: true in the client initialization but it didn't seem to do anything. I'm not even sure if it's a valid parameter for JS environments as I've seen it being suggested for similar issues in Python.


socket_keepalive option is not a valid parameter.

SO_KEEPALIVE is the correct parameter, you can check the same in MS_DOC

In Node.js, when using the redis library for creating Redis clients, you don't directly interact with the socket object in most cases.

So Instead of using SO_KEEPALIVE, You can configure the keepAlive option through the socket configuration object when creating the Redis client. It will correctly manage the underlying Node.js socket implementation.

It helps in keeping the connection alive even during the period of inactivity by sending periodic keep-alive packets.

Here I have use the keepalive parameter I am able to connect with client without reconnection.


My Server.js file:
const redis = require('redis');

const dbIndex = process.env.REDIS_DB_INDEX || 0; 
const DEFAULT_TTL = parseInt(process.env.FACETS_CACHE_TTL, 10) || 1800;

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: `rediss://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:6380`,
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    socket: {
        keepAlive: true, // Enable keep-alive
        tls: {
            servername: process.env.REDIS_HOST
        },
        reconnectStrategy: (retries) => {
            if (retries < 10) {
               
                return 2000;
            } else {
              
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
});

redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
redisClient.on('reconnecting', () => console.log('Reconnecting to Redis...'));
let isFirstConnection = true;

redisClient.on('ready', () => {
    if (isFirstConnection) {
        console.log('\nSuccessfully connected to Redis');
        isFirstConnection = false;
    } else {
        console.log('\nSuccessfully reconnected to Redis');
    }
});

(async () => {
    try {
        await redisClient.connect();
        await redisClient.sendCommand(['SELECT', dbIndex]);
        console.log(`database index: ${dbIndex}`);
        console.log(`DEFAULT_TTL = ${DEFAULT_TTL} seconds\n`);
       
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to Redis:', err);
    }
})();


If the connection to Redis is lost, the client should attempt to reconnect with an exponential backoff strategy. So, structure the reconnect strategy to handle transient issues better and provide a gradual backoff mechanism.

Thanks @SimoneSacchito, Use the option retryStrategy to  fine-tune reconnection behavior.



